# Is it possible to insert data to 2 tables from 1 controller?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is my database. I want to make a stored procedure to insert data into the Reservation table. I want to insert room_id, data check-in and other fields but instead of guest_id I want to put first name, last name, Phone and other fields from the Guest table. Is this possible?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create 2 stored procedures. one for saving the guest info and one for saving the reservation info.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SaveGuest(@firstName varcahr(50),@lastName varchar(50),@phone varchar(15))
AS
 BEGIN

    INSERT INTO Guest(FirstName,LastName,Phone) VALUES (@firstName,@lastName,@phone);
    RETURN SCOPE_IDENTITY()

 END
```

Procedure to call Second Proc

```
CREATE PROCEDUE SaveReservation(@roomId int,@guestId int,@price decimal)
AS
 BEGIN
   INSERT INTO Reservation(Room_ID,Guest_ID,Price) VALUES (@roomID,@guestId,@price)
   RETURN SCOPE_IDENTITY()
 END
```

This is a sample. You need to add field for all your db columns which is not null.

Now create 2 methods to save these data. `SaveGuest` and `SaveReservation`. Return the Newly Saved Guest ID  from your SaveGuest method. Now in your action method call, the SaveGuest method first. check the return value of the method. If it is a valid number, That means the guest info is saved. USe that Guest ID in saving the Second part (Reservation);  Something like this

```
public ActionResult SAve(YourViewMolde model)
{
int guestId=  SaveGuest("john","alex",....);
if(guestID>0)
 {
   SaveReservation(guestId,34,...);
 }
 else
 {
   model.AddModelError("","Error in saving Guest info!");
 }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Whatever data is posted you can insert however you want to as many tables as you want. A controller has nothing to do with a table and thus there is no restriction.

I suggest trying to write something and if you can get it to work post your attempt here( stack overflow...not this particular posting) describing what isn't working. That more fits the SO format rather than a vague non code specioc question.